# How to Execute a Javascript in Internet Explorer from Command Line?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, command-line, automation

Recently at my job we have been wanting to automate our deployment process with new machines. I figured the best way to do this was by launching IE (since it's the default browser that's installed via Litetouch) via command line, which the generic code for it is as follows:

```
iexplore.exe http://reg.cmich.edu
```

Which works as expected; however the next part of the automation process is to pass IE at least a javascript file that can select the building I want to register a new NIC device at, then on the next pass I would pass it my administrative credentials.

For the most part, I can figure out by scrounging the net how to get Javascript to execute certain things in a browser like clicking links and entering text into text boxes. I'm just wondering if there's any way during running my batch script that I can pass IE a .js file to execute after the browser opens.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at Selenium?

Comment: Would I need to install Selenium on the machine I wish to automate? Because if so, then that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass IE completely by using `cscript.exe` to run JavaScript.

```
> cscript.exe "path/to/file.js"
```

`cscript.exe` is in `c:\windows\system32`.

---

Keep in mind that globals like `window` and `document` will not be available because you have no head.

Comment: Ah! Ok, thanks a lot for the information, I'll attempt it and get back with the results.

Quick question: Would I have to run cscript after launching IE to have it execute in the browser (in this case, current active window), or do I have to pass it an argument to execute the .js file with respect to IE?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go enable by command

1) Go to Start -> Run
2) Type : CMD (then enter)
3) You will get command prompt window on screen.
4) Type below command and ten enter :

regsvr32 jscript.dll

5) Now check Internet Explorer. You will have javascript enabled.
Hope this would help you to solve your problem.